# iOS: Go back to entry point view controller which is not part of navigation controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I have a login view controller which is outside my navigation controller. When a user logs out, I want them to be back to the login view controller. I am using `SWRevealViewController` and Storyboards.

User Flow:

-> Login View Controller -> `SWRevealViewController`-> `UINavigationController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set window.rootViewController to the login view controller.

Comment: That worked, but will it clear nav controller from memory or do I have to handle garbage collection. I am using ARC

Comment: @AsifAlamgir It should release the nav controller unless you're explicitly retaining them somewhere in your code.